# phpseclib: Convert ECDSA PrivateKey to 64 character hexadecimal

Tags: php, ethereum, private-key, pem, phpseclib

I'm trying to generate an Ethereum address in PHP and part of the requirements is generating a 64 character hex private key. I'm using phpseclib already in my project, and decided to use it's classes for generating a private key. The recommended is the `secp256k1` curve and I used that as well

```
$privateKey = EC::createKey('secp256k1');

$privateKeyString = $privateKey->toString('PKCS8');
```

The output I get is something like this(in PEM format)

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n
MIGEAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKBG0wawIBAQQgDknmmpdnS+MvAylQDbXl\r\n
WECAG51RuIViJFLw/0aR40yhRANCAARpIut7yqacMbI9TW/aT5frWKpjoDOAL15l\r\n
A/5rE+6+o/AbWES5bHej1U/ygxyqlwVizCABCSeWZf5CNoTy8nMt\r\n
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have tried so many ways to get the required 64 character(256bits) hex code but none has worked. I tried decoding the PEM using `base64_decode` and then using the `bin2hex` function, but the output string is almost 310 characters. Removing the header and footer, i got an output of 268 characters.However, if i check the length using `$privateKey->getLength()`, I get an output of 256. The problem now is, how do I get the 64 character hex string???

Can someone please help me with how to achieve this with the library?

Comment: Unless Ethereum has some magic in it, that key data is not getting any shorter than 135 bytes. Encoded as hex it would be 270 bytes. I think you've misunderstood or mixed something up along the way.

Comment: Strangely, it was achievable on this : https://github.com/kornrunner/php-ethereum-address/tree/main

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have found a solution. I'll leave it here for anyone who encounter's the same problem, My solution was inspired by [@neubert's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247081/11209184).

```
 $privateKey = EC::createKey('secp256k1');
 $jwk = JWK::load($privateKey->toString('JWK'));

 $publicKeyHex = $jwk['QA'][0]->toHex() . $jwk['QA'][1]->toHex();
 $privateKeyHex = $jwk['dA']->toHex();

 $hashGenerator = new \phpseclib3\Crypt\Hash('keccak256');
 $hash = $hash->hash($pub);

 $walletAddress = self::toChecksum(substr($hash, -40));
 $walletPrivateKey = '0x' . $privateKeyHex;
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Maybe post the `self::toChecksum` function as well?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem now is, how do I get the 64 character hex string???

Does this do what you're wanting?:

```
$key = json_decode($key->toString('JWK'))->keys[0];
$pub = $key->x . $key->y;
```

> I'm trying to generate an Ethereum address in PHP

Like this?:

```
$key = \phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader::load("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGEAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKBG0wawIBAQQgDknmmpdnS+MvAylQDbXl
WECAG51RuIViJFLw/0aR40yhRANCAARpIut7yqacMbI9TW/aT5frWKpjoDOAL15l
A/5rE+6+o/AbWES5bHej1U/ygxyqlwVizCABCSeWZf5CNoTy8nMt
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

$key = json_decode($key->toString('JWK'))->keys[0];
$pub = $key->x . $key->y;

$hash = new \phpseclib3\Crypt\Hash('keccak256');
$hash = $hash->hash($pub);
$address = substr($hash, -20);
$address = '0x' . strtolower(bin2hex($address));

echo $address;
```

Comment: The public key output was incorrect. Apparently, the x, y and d of the JWK key were encoded in base256. Had to dig into phpseclib to see how they converted to JWK, and how their JWK class itself. Thanks for this though, it inspired my final solution. I sent it as a new reply